# How to convert string into JSON format

Tags: php

iam facing difficulty to convert a string which i retrieve it from DB.

$test = '{1:1,2:4}';

First the string is json malformed because of the key is not in string. But how can i convert the key into string and then covert into JSON object?

Comment: How did a malformed JSON string get in to your DB? Fix that problem and this one goes away

Answer (score 0):

String $test is not json formatted correct. It requires keys is string type.
If your $test is just a object have key and value is all number. You can reformat it.

```
$test = '{1:1,2:4}';
$formatKeyValues= substr($test, 1, -1);
$keys= [];
$values= [];

 foreach(explode(",", $formatKeyValues) as $atribute) {
     //php 7.2 above
     [$key, $value] = explode(":", $atribute);
     $keys[]= $key;
     $values[]= (int)$value;
 };

$jsonfromatted = json_encode(array_combine($keys, $values));
$object = json_decode($jsonfromatted);
var_dump($object);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may able to convert using regex.

```
$json = preg_replace("/(\d+):/", '"$1"', $test);
```

More on [preg_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Answer (score -2):

The format seems like generated by Php serialize() function. Try unserialize()

Comment: Wouldn't it have an `a:2:` at the start if it was serialized? https://3v4l.org/uWECN